# How to create a if estatement inside a function to check file type in vimscript?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I need to check the file type I have opened in Vim to do one thing or another inside a function.

This is what my `vimrc` looks like:

```
function! MyFunction()
    autocmd filetype typescript <C-V>%
    autocmd filetype go <C-V>%
endfunction

nnoremap <Leadar>f :call MyFunction()<CR>
```

Next to `<C-V>%` will be more instructions, but for now this is what I'm testing.

My function has to detect the file I have openend, according to its type do one thing or another. I'm doing this inside a function because in the near future I will move this to a separete plugin, but for now it is my `vimrc` file.

Another thing I've tried already and I know it works is this

```
autocmd filetype typescript nnoremap <Leader>f <C-V>% DoTypescriptThings
autocmd filetype go nnoremap <Leader>f <C-V>% DoGolangThings
```

If I move this lines outside of a function body I works. But this way I couldn't change the `<Leader> KEY` easily if I make this a plugin. That's why I moved it to a function.

How can I make my function detect my types so my function works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can understand clearly, you actually want to pull out the filetype checking from auto-command so that remapping the main key (`<LEADER>f`) becomes easy.

You can do this by using `&filetype`.
Your function will look something like this:

```
function! MyFunction()
    if &filetype ==# 'typescript'
        autocmd filetype typescript <C-V>%

        " Now you dont need autocmds here to be precise;
        " But you may consider some other autocmd-events in future
        " Until then a simple :execute or :execute "normal!..." should be sufficient instead

    elseif &filetype ==# 'go'
        autocmd filetype go <C-V>%
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <Leadar>f :call MyFunction()<CR>
```

Now considering the fact that autocmd also does the same thing (checking filetype and applying a mapping) so I guess your main motivation is not to use autocmd but to be able to remap main key (`<LEADER>f`) easily.

So in conclusion, I would suggest to not use autocmd here and go with a function definition only so that one key can rule your function call. (Of course, unless you decide to use some other autocmd-events too)

Comment: Thank you so mucho for this! I used this as a base.